# Error while installing Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: mongooose@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\manas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-07T21_54_15_105Z-debug.log

Comment: Have you tried typing `mongoose` instead of `mongooose`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what command you have entered ? 
**You can try :**

```
$ sudo npm install -g mongoose
```

**-g** for global installation [This command will work if you are on linx machine and will install the latest one ]

Or

**If you are on windows :**
 you can try : `npm install -g mongoose`

All these commands will automatically install the latest version , You dont need to explicitly mention it

Comment: npm install mongoose --save

Comment: OP you can also try this. It will save it as a dev dependency to your project